# Running jupyter kernels on different CPU cores locally?

Tags: windows, jupyter, multicore

I'm using Jupyter to train a deep network with Keras + Tensorflow. I'm using my Windows laptop's Intel i5 CPU, and training takes some time.

I'd like to work on a side project without slowing down the training. Can I launch a new Jupyter kernel on another CPU core ? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows allows you to set processor affinity in the task manager.

Launch the application.  Open the task manager and go to the process, left click to set the affinity.  Just choose one processor.

Launch the second application and repeat with a different affinity.